# Convert Parallels VM to Virtual Box VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, conversion, parallels

The question describes well what I need but here are some more details about the circumstances.

With Parallels Desktop 4 running under Linux, I have a number of Windows 7 Virtual Machines. Sadly, Parallels has not been upgraded for a while, so I am trying some other VMS and VirtualBox was highly recommended. Particularly, it is provided with the OpenSUSE Linux distribution. This will avoid the problem and allow me to keep up to date with the latest OpenSUSE.

**So my question is, how can I convert a Parallels VM into a Virtual Box one?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VirtualBox can use Parallels (.hdd) disks in simple-format without conversion. If the disk does not use the simple format, it must be converted first using the Parallels Image Tool.

But I would uninstall Parallels Tools first (if you have it installed on the VM) and make a backup copy of the VM. Then create a new VirtualBox machine, matching the CPU and memory settings as closely as you can to the Parallels machine.

You may also refer to [this article](http://www.neilturner.me.uk/2008/11/19/how_to_migrate_a_parallel.html) on migration, although it is a bit old and recommends using VMWare Converter, which I would avoid if you can.

Comment: It seems to be looking for .vhd, ,vdi or ,vmdk files... which my Parallels VM does not have. Do I need to rename something? I've got an empty .hdd file and .xml file in the directory of the VM.

Comment: What version of VirtualBox are you using? And what version of OpenSUSE? It looks like Parallels disk support was added in 3.1.0.

Comment: VirtualBox is 3.0.6 and OpenSUSE is 11.2. I've been trapped at 11.2 because of Parallels.

Comment: Getting closer, updated VirtualBox to 4.0.4.12 which now sees the .hdd file but gives an error: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) - I tried with the VM not running and running, same error.

Comment: I would guess that the disk is a newer Parallels disks (version 3 or 4). Try [converting it](http://download.parallels.com/desktop/v4/docs/en/Parallels_Image_Tool_Users_Guide/23056.htm) down to version 2 disk and have another go. Sorry for the goose chase!

Comment: Thank you for your patience. Getting there. After conversion, VirtualBox accepts to add the disk and creates a VM. Only it does not start, it gives the error: 'VT-x/AMD-V hardware acceleration has been enabled, but is not operational.... Please ensure you have VT-x/AMD-V enabled in the BIOS of your host computer'. Well, I tried but I have no such option. Parallels has no trouble running the VM, so maybe it is not 'properly migrated'. What can I do?

Comment: Okay, this error isn't an issue with the VM, but is an issue with VirtualBox running on your hardware. Go into your VM's settings (System > Acceleration) and uncheck the items there. You should be okay running without VT-x, but it depends on if you're using multiple CPUs on your VM.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this and when taking it off... it says 'You are using a 64-bit client OS and this is required and will be enabled automatically'... If I start the machine and ignore warnings, it keeps trying to boot infinitely. Would using a different version of VirtualBox let it run the Parallels machine without this?

Comment: Well, from your latest comment, it seems at least the 'conversion' worked, so I'll make this answer accepted and open another question for the VT-x/AMD-V issue.

Comment: Here is the new question for the VT-x/AMD-V issue: http://superuser.com/questions/331201/vt-x-amd-v-work-around-for-virtualbox

Answer (score 8):

The procedure is like this: (Parallels Desktop 12)

1) Prepare the Parallels VM by removing the Parallels Tools and anything that is “special" (mounts, shared folders, etc)..

```
sudo /usr/lib/parallels-tools/install -r
```

2) Copy the HDD file from inside the PVM OS X package into the open file system (Finder, Right Click, Show Package Content). Generally, the first HDD file contains the bootable system.

3) Use this command line tool while being in the directory where the HDD file is located:

```
$/Applications/Parallels\ Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_disk_tool convert --hdd my-parallels-disk1.hdd --plain
```

4) The resulting HDD file replaces the source file and still is a package. So enter again and copy the HDS (not HDD) file into the open file system, best where the (empty) VirtualBox VM is located (You can use the “file” command on the HDS to verify that it is indeed a bootable disk image).

5) Rename the file giving it a HDD extension.

6) Add the file as (start-up) disk to an “empty” VirtualBox VM, (update settings), boot and enjoy.

More info [here](https://www.rational-pi.be/2016/10/converting-a-parallels-virtual-machine-to-virtualbox/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This worked for me with Parallels Desktop 11 and VirtualBox 5.0.18. No other method seemed to work and it's a Linux VM so I couldn't use VMware Converter.

Answer (score 4):

If someone is using Parallels 11, 12 or 13 and VirtualBox 5 - it is much much easier.

Step 1: Expand the Package Contents of the parallel's HDD

Step 2: Within that there is an HDS file, ideally there will be only 1 file containing the data (unless split option was used), just double check the size of the file which is a good indication of the file you are looking for.

Step 3: Copy the HDS file to a new location that VirtualBox can access, rename the file and change its extension to hdd.

Step 4: Attach the newly copied file directly with the VirtualBox.

Step 5: Test everything, this is good to go.

Step 6: Run the guest OS, uninstall old parallels tool and install VirtualBox guest tools.

These steps will get finished within minutes and no conversion needed.

I have just finished executing all of these steps day before and tested.

After this, I executed the below listed Optional steps, so that the hdd file gets converted into VDI file. With VDI file the VirtualBox gets more control: most important one being optimizing the free space, which i sorely needed.

Optional Steps: (Switch off guest OS before this)

Step 7: From within VirtualBox tool, Open Global Tools, it will list all harddisks

Step 8: Use Copy function, this will export the attached HDD file to any other compatible options: VDI, VHD, VMDK and more, after researching which is best option i chose VDI - since this is native to VirtualBox.

In future if i need to export the Virtual machine to some other format, then VirtualBox has export option and supports "Open Virtualisation Format".

Basically with the above procedure, you skip the parallels tool for conversion, somewhere VMware converter was proposed, you skip that too. You will only need 1 single tool: VirtualBox, to complete all the steps.

Comment: Just to note this works with Parallels 15 and VirtualBox 6 as well.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how this will go, but you could try [this guide I found](http://www.neilturner.me.uk/2008/11/19/how_to_migrate_a_parallel.html) that uses the VMware Converter.