# Is there an easy way to convert a Parallels disk to a VirtualBox disk?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, import, parallels

The question has been asked before, *but* there appear to be no current solutions.

I have a current version of Parallels 11, and a current version of VirtualBox 4.3. I have an existing Windows image in Parallels, which I would like to use in VirtualBox. All on my iMac running El Capitan 10.11.4

I have tried to create a new VirtualBox machine with an existing virtual hard drive. This is a `.hdd` file extracted from a `.pvm` package. While VirtualBox sees the image, it fails with the message:

`Failed to open the hard disk file … the medium … can't be used as the requested device type.`

Most solutions I have found involve using Parallels Image Tool, which, as far as I can tell, is no longer part of the package.

Is there a straight forward solution to importing the image into VirtualBox?

Comment: You did shut down the Parallels instance first, not just suspend it?

Comment: @Tetsujin I did. I also deleted a snapshot dependent on it.

Comment: OK, just checking. I haven't used VirtualBox, iso can't help further, but that's always one to watch out for in Parallels. Wish you luck :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Parallels VM to Virtual Box VM?](http://superuser.com/questions/330335/convert-parallels-vm-to-virtual-box-vm)

Answer (score 14):

The procedure is like this: (Parallels Desktop 12)

1) Prepare the Parallels VM by removing the Parallels Tools and anything that is “special" (mounts, shared folders, etc)..

```
sudo /usr/lib/parallels-tools/install -r
```

2) Copy the HDD file from inside the PVM OS X package into the open file system (Finder, Right Click, Show Package Contents). Generally, the first HDD file contains the bootable system.

3) Use this command line tool while being in the directory where the HDD file is located:

```
$/Applications/Parallels\ Desktop.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_disk_tool convert --hdd my-parallels-disk1.hdd --plain
```

4) The resulting HDD file replaces the source file and still is a package. Open the package (Finder, Right Click, Show Package Contents) and copy the HDS (not HDD) file into the open file system, best where the (empty) VirtualBox VM is located (You can use the “file” command on the HDS to verify that it is indeed a bootable disk image).

5) Rename the file giving it a HDD extension.

6) Add the file as (start-up) disk to an “empty” VirtualBox VM, (update settings), boot and enjoy.

More info [here](http://blog.carl.pro/2016/10/converting-a-parallels-virtual-machine-to-virtualbox/).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Just FYI, when you encounter several questions and the same answer solves both, consider whether the questions are duplicates.  If so, decide which one makes the best reference Q&A and flag the other as a possible duplicate.  If that's not the case, a better way to post to avoid duplication once you hit 50 rep is to just post a comment on the second question, pointing to your answer on the first.

Comment: I wasn't excepting it will work but yeah it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Website is down but you may reach its archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20161205094233/http://blog.carl.pro/2016/10/converting-a-parallels-virtual-machine-to-virtualbox/